# axios transformRequest - how to alter JSON payload

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) in my Express API and I want to transform the payload before sending it off to another API. axios has just the thing for this called [`transformRequest`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config). This is where I ran into issues though.

The code I have looks like:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'api-url.com',
  transformRequest: [
    (data, headers) => {
      const encryptedString = encryptPayload(JSON.stringify(data));

      data = {
        SecretStuff: encryptedString,
      };

      return data;
    },
  ],  
});

// firing off my request using the instance above:
const postData = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'James',
};
instance.post('/getStuff', postData)
```

and ultimately, I want to post `api-url.com` the JSON: `{"SecretStuff": "some-base64-string"}` - not the `postData` object shown above.

From the docs, it says: "The last function in the array must return a string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, FormData or Stream" - but of course here I am returning an object, data. Oddly enough in the axios docs it shows them returning `data` from `transformRequest`, but in their case that must be the correct data type.

How do I *actually* transform a payload with axios?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wouldn't you want to `JSON.stringify()` your transformed post data? Like below:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'api-url.com',
    transformRequest: [
        (data, headers) => {
            const encryptedString = encryptPayload(JSON.stringify(data));

            data = {
                SecretStuff: encryptedString,
            };

            return JSON.stringify(data);
        },
    ],  
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but then what would be sent in the request?  Would it just be that stringified object? Would that be treated as JSON? Right now I am getting `Bad Request` responses from the API I am hitting because it expects a JSON object that looks like `{"SecretStuff": "some-base64-string"}`.

Comment: Follow up to my above comment, stringifying the data solved the issue. I also had to set the proper headers `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', Accept: 'application/json' }` in order to get the POST to work (which traditionally Axios has done for me, but in this case because it is a custom instance I needed to manually set them). Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's weird and counter-intuitive that data needs to be `JSON.stringify`-ied at this point in the API (even though, in my case I only wanted to tamper with the headers) but that's what it took to get it to work in my case.

Answer (score 29):

```
axios.create({
    transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
        // modify data here
        return data;
    }, ...axios.defaults.transformRequest]
});
```

have to append [the original `axios.defaults.transformRequest`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/4f189ec80ce01a0275d87d24463ef12b16715d9b/lib/defaults.js#L31-L55) to the `transformRequest` option here..

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me in TypeScript, inspired by the `concat` solution from Phil here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949237/2339352

The goal here was to use the [humps](https://github.com/domchristie/humps) library to convert to/from a snake case Python API:

```
this.axios = axios.create({
    transformResponse: (data: any) => {
        return humps.camelizeKeys(JSON.parse(data))
    },
    transformRequest: [(data: any) => {
        return humps.decamelizeKeys(data);
    }].concat(axios.defaults.transformRequest ? axios.defaults.transformRequest : [])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To amend the values instead of override the output in the request I would do this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
baseURL: 'api-url.com',
transformRequest: [
    (data, headers) => {
        data.append('myKey','myValue');            
        return data;
    },
]
});
```