# Using Axios transformRequest results in 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios

I just upgraded my react app to axios 0.25.0 and started getting http 415 Unsupported Media type errors in some REST POST/PUT API calls. These calls all have one thing in common, they include a date field in the request body.

I use an axios transformRequest to ensure that any date fields are sent to the API in local time rather than the JSON default UTC.

When I look at the header for these requests the "Content-Type" has changed from "application/json" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and is subsequently rejected by the REST API which expects [FromBody] JSON object.
Rather than change the API I have added an axios interceptor to ensure the header "Content-Type" is "application/json". This fixes the problem but I do not like the fix.

**transformRequest**

```js
const serialiseDateLocal = (data: any) => {

    Date.prototype.toJSON = function() {
        // dateToString returns local time in specified format
        return dateToString(this, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ");
    }; 
    
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
axios.defaults.transformRequest = [serialiseDateLocal];
```

**interceptor**

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
        if(req.headers) {
            req.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json';
        }
        
        return req;
    });
```

Why is the content-type changing to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" when the transform is used? is there a way to prevent this or a better way to handle it?

UPDATE:
Setting default headers negates the need for the interceptor.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.put["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.patch["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

UPDATE:
Based on Phils comments problem turned out to be me **replacing** the transformRequest chain as well as returning a string from my transformer - solution is.

```js
const serialiseDateLocal: AxiosRequestTransformer  = (data: any) => {

    if (data instanceof Date) {
        return dateToString(data, serializedFormat);
    } 
    
    if (typeof data === "object" && data !== null) {
        return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([ key, val ]) =>
          [ key, serialiseDateLocal(val) ]))
    }

    return data;
}
axios.defaults.transformRequest = [serialiseDateLocal].concat(axios.defaults.transformRequest);
```

Comment: If you're overwriting the `Date` prototype, you don't need to use a request transformer at all. I wouldn't recommend doing that though; a transformer that actually changes the request data is preferable (see the duplicate post)

Comment: Why was this marked as duplicate/closed - this question is not how to implement a date transformer but why the request header content-type changes when a transformer is used. The linked question does not answer the question or even address it (the transformer implementation there still results in the same issue).

Comment: You're right. I've re-opened your question however my previous comment still stands and you'd be better off actually transforming the request data as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70690032/283366).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default content-type](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.25.0/lib/defaults.js#L7) for Axios requests is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

One thing the [default request transformer](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.25.0/lib/defaults.js#L54) does is set the appropriate content-type for the request data...

> ```js
> if (utils.isObject(data) || (headers && headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/json')) {
>   setContentTypeIfUnset(headers, 'application/json');
>   return stringifySafely(data);
> }
> ```

Since you're replacing the entire `transformRequest` chain, you now miss out on this.

You should either handle it in your transformer, eg

```js
import { AxiosRequestTransformer } from "axios"

const serialiseDateLocal: AxiosRequestTransformer = (data, headers) => {
  // TODO: actually transform the request, don't just modify the Date prototype

  headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

  return JSON.stringify(data)
}
```

or as is more common, unshift your transformer onto the existing chain and have it return a plain object, letting the default transformer do its work

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  transformRequest: [ serialiseDateLocal ].concat(axios.defaults.transformRequest)
})
```

---

I'm not sure yet why your interceptor wasn't setting the header correctly. I suspect it's a race condition and it might be worth [raising a bug report](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/new?assignees=&labels=status%3Apossible%20bug&template=---bug-report.md&title=).

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Your comment about replacing the transformRequest chain was key. The Solution was simply concatenating existing transformations and returning an object from my transformation.